# Using DefaultHttpClient between Activities

Tags: java, android, cookies, httpclient

I have an DefaultHttpClient that don't check for certificates that I use at both activity:

```
public function clientWithoutCertificateCheck() {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try{
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
    } catch (Exception e) { }

    return httpClient;
}
```

and it does login at a page inside this same activity.

After start the other activity I save it's cookies:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
List<Cookie> cookies = httpClient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
for(Cookie cookie : cookies)
{
    String cookieString = cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue() + "; domain=" + cookie.getDomain();                        
    CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(cookie.getDomain(), cookieString);  
}
```

Then I'm trying to get the same httpClient at another activity.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = clientWithoutCertificateCheck();
String url = "https://academicos.unilasalle.edu.br/";
String[] keyValueSets = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url).split(";");
for(String cookie : keyValueSets)
{
    String[] keyValue = cookie.split("=");
    String key = keyValue[0];
    String value = "";
    if(keyValue.length>1) value = keyValue[1];
    httpClient.getCookieStore().addCookie(new BasicClientCookie(key, value));
}
```

and for some reason he isn't logged in anymore.

Can someone help me solve this?

Comment: How do you get the original httpClient from another activity? post your clientWithoutCertificateCheck() method may help other people locate your problem.

Comment: I improved the question. The first piece of code get's repeated in both activities in order to get a new Http Client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, obviously by calling clientWithoutCertificateCheck() always return a newly created httpClient, not the same one from previous activity. So on the server side, it may think these are different incoming connection and associate with different sessions/cookies.

Activity's life cycle is quite transitory, usually it gets created/destroyed many times during application running time. From my point of view, it is not reasonable to bind httpClient to Activity.
If you want to retain/use single httpClient instance cross avtivities, consider using service, implement/centralize your http related stuff into your HttpService, and start/bind service for all activities that need use http service. hope that help.